# Using Item from Hashmap causes segmentation fault

Tags: c, hashmap, cjson

I am trying to fill a hashmap of Spritesheets. The data for the Spritesheet is read from a json file.

I am using [hashmap.c](https://github.com/tidwall/hashmap.c) for the hashmap and [cJSON](https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON) for parsing the json data

**The SpriteSheet struct**

```c
typedef struct
{
    char* name;
    char* path;
    int width;
    int height;
} SpriteSheet;
```

**Example Json Data**

```json
"spriteSheets": [
    {
        "name": "player",
        "path": "player.png",
        "width": 192,
        "height": 64
    }
]
```

**The Code**

```c
spriteSheetHashMap = hashmap_new(sizeof(SpriteSheet), 0, 0, 0, spriteSheetHash, spriteSheetCompare, NULL, NULL);

cJSON* textureJson = cJSON_Parse(textureJsonString);

cJSON* spriteSheetsJson = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(textureJson, "spriteSheets");

cJSON* spriteSheetJson;
cJSON_ArrayForEach(spriteSheetJson, spriteSheetsJson)
{
    char* sheetName = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "name")->valuestring;
    char* sheetPath = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "path")->valuestring;
    int sheetWidth = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "width")->valueint;
    int sheetHeight = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "height")->valueint;

    hashmap_set(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){
        .name=sheetName,
        .path=sheetPath,
        .width=sheetWidth, .height=sheetHeight,
        .spriteHashMap=spriteHashMap
    });
}

cJSON_Delete(textureJson);
```

When I access this in some other file, I get a segmentation fault

```c
SpriteSheet* spriteSheet = hashmap_get(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){ .name="map" });
printf("%s, %s", spriteSheet->name, spriteSheet->path); // This line causes the segmentation fault
```

But, If I add the items explicitly, it doesn't segfault and prints the values

```c
hashmap_set(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){
        .name="map",
        .path="image.png",
        .width=4, .height=8
});
// OR
char* a = "map";
char* b = "image.png";
hashmap_set(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){
        .name=a,
        .path=b,
        .width=4, .height=8
});
```

Why is this happening?
How can I fix it?

Comment: I don't think `valuestring` makes a copy of the string, it just returns the pointer. When you do `cJSON_Delete(textureJson);` all the nested pointers are freed.

Comment: Wow, it works. Please post this as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    char* sheetName = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "name")->valuestring;
    char* sheetPath = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(spriteSheetJson, "path")->valuestring;
```

The two lines of code above get pointers to parts of `spriteSheetJson`.

```
hashmap_set(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){
    .name=sheetName,
    .path=sheetPath,
    .width=sheetWidth, .height=sheetHeight,
    .spriteHashMap=spriteHashMap
    });
```

The line of code above saves those pointers.

```
cJSON_Delete(textureJson);
```

But this line of code above deletes the object that those pointers pointed into. They now point to where the JSON object's data used to be.

```
SpriteSheet* spriteSheet = hashmap_get(spriteSheetHashMap, &(SpriteSheet){ .name="map" });
printf("%s, %s", spriteSheet->name, spriteSheet->path); // This line causes the segmentation fault
```

This code tries to dereference the pointers you saved, pointers that pointed to parts of an object that no longer exists.

You need to make copies of the data. The easiest way is to call `strdup` on the values returned by `cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive`. Then they're yours to `free` when you are done.